# How to estimate the order of the ARDL model in R?

Tags: time-series, model-selection, aic, lags, ardl

I have to build the best fitting ARDL model with d(log(GDP)) as the dependent variable and d(int. rate) as a regressor and use AIC for the lag selection with maximum 12 lags for the regressor and 12 lags for the dependent variable and then validate my model. I was wondering how to find the ARDL model with the lowest AIC in R. I'm attaching the code used to estimate it. The problem is that I cannot find any function that gives me the order of it, and dynardl.auto.correlate function allows me to check the AIC but in my case I would have to find too many combinations... ARDL(0,0), ARDL(0,1),.. and so on until all possible combination up to 12 are done both for the regressor and for the dependent variable.
`res12=dynardl(gdplogdiff~interestratediff1,lags=list("gdplogdiff"=1:12,"interestratediff1"=1:12))`